# clojure: Removing maps from lazy-seq of maps

Tags: clojure

I have a lazy-seq of maps and I'm attempting to remove maps from that lazy-seq based on the return value from another function. The other function will return true or false depending on whether or not a call of get returns a value equal to the parameter. The problem is the function isn't working correctly and I'm not too sure why.

```
    (defn filter-by-name "Filter by names" [name m]
       (if (= name (get m :name_of_person)) true false)) 
        ;To be called on each map

    (defn remove-nonmatching-values "Remove anything not matching" [filter-val all-maps]
      (map #(remove (filter-by-name filter-val %)) all-maps)) 
       ;trying to call on the lazy seq
```

Comment: The `if` is redundant, you can simply write `(defn filter-by-name "Filter by names" [name m] (= name (get m :name_of_person)))`

Comment: Just noticed that, thanks.

Comment: In order to reduce verbosity the way to say thanks if you find a contribution valuable is to upvote the answer or comment, have a look into the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) _This site is all about getting answers. It's not a discussion forum. There's no chit-chat._ :)

Comment: I'm not able to upvote otherwise that's what I would have done, just need 2 more rep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to call `remove` on the sequence of maps.

```
 (defn remove-nonmatching-values 
    "Remove anything not matching" 
    [filter-val all-maps]
    (remove #(filter-by-name filter-val %) all-maps))
```

Check Clojure's [remove](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/remove) doc

> (remove pred coll)
>
> Returns a lazy sequence of the items in coll for which
>     (pred item) returns false. pred must be free of side-effects.
>    Returns a transducer when no collection is provided.

Comment: When I call that as follows:
        (remove-nonmatching-values "hello" ({:name_of_peson "hello"} {:name_of_peson "bye"}))
It returns ().

Thanks

Comment: You are not passing a proper list but calling a function you should call this way: `(remove-nonmatching-values "hello" '({:name_of_person "hello"} {:name_of_person "bye"}))`

Comment: This function appears to me to remove *matching* values, not non-matching ones.

Comment: @m0butt You have mis-spelled `:name_of_person` as `:name_of_peson` in your example.

Comment: @Thumbnail didn't catch that, regardless it's working now. thanks

Answer (score 0):

A function that produces the test-function you need for a given `name` is

```
(defn name-matcher [name]
  (fn [m] (= name (:name_of_person m))))
```

All you have to do is filter the maps accordingly:

```
(defn retain-matching-maps [name maps]
  (filter (name-matcher name) maps))
```

For example,

```
(retain-matching-maps "hello" (list {:name_of_person "hello"} {:name_of_person "bye"}))
;({:name_of_person "hello"})
```

I have got rid of

- the comments (which are implied by the function names)
- the `if` (as noted by [Guillermo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31791052/1562315))
- the `get` (Keywords - or maps - are implicit `get` functions)
- the double negative in the function name `remove-nonmatching-values`.

You could also use `:name` instead of `:name-of-person`. The more succinctly you express your program, the less likely you are to make mistakes.